# Symfony EntityType doesn't show all records when multiple and expanded are disabled

Tags: symfony

Why does database records prohibited to show all records when I use drop down field in Symfony 3.

I have form which has `EntityType:class`, I use this form to display the records from my db into drop down html entity.

The problem is when I set `expanded` and `multiple` to false just to set the field in drop down. Not all records are showing. But, if I activated those  two parameters in true, complete records are showing.

Here's my code in form.

```
->add('currency', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => BranchCurrency::class,
                'choice_value' => 'id',
                'choice_label' => function($currency){
                    return $currency->getName() . ' (' . $currency->getCode() .') - '.$currency->getRate().'';
                },
                'placeholder' => 'Choose currency',
                'query_builder' => function (BranchCurrencyRepository $er) {
                    return $er->findAllActiveBuyingCurrencies();
                },
                'multiple' => false, <--- If I set this parameter to false, not all records are showing.
                'expanded' => false, <--- If I set this parameter to false, not all records are showing.
            ])
```

UPDATE:

In case you need to see the Entity class and Repository class.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="branch_currency")
 * @UniqueEntity(
 *     fields={"branch", "currency"},
 *     message="This currency is already using on this branch.",
 *     errorPath="branch"
 * )
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="MontealBundle\Repository\BranchCurrencyRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class BranchCurrency
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Branch", inversedBy="branchCurrency")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $branch;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Currency", inversedBy="assignedCurrencies")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $currency;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", precision=10, scale=4)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $rate;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $type;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
     */
    private $code;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $createdAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $updatedAt;

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getBranch()
    {
        return $this->branch;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $branch
     */
    public function setBranch($branch)
    {
        $this->branch = $branch;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getCurrency()
    {
        return $this->currency;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $currency
     */
    public function setCurrency($currency)
    {
        $this->currency = $currency;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getCode()
    {
        return $this->code;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $code
     */
    public function setCode($code)
    {
        $this->code = $code;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getRate()
    {
        return $this->rate;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $rate
     */
    public function setRate($rate)
    {
        $this->rate = $rate;
    }

    public function getCreatedAt()
    {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getType()
    {
        return $this->type;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $name
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $type
     */
    public function setType($type)
    {
        $this->type = $type;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist
     */
    public function setCreatedAt()
    {
        $this->createdAt = new \DateTime();
    }

    public function getUpdatedAt()
    {
        return $this->updatedAt;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PreUpdate()
     */
    public function setUpdatedAt()
    {
        $this->updatedAt = new \DateTime();
    }

    public function __toString() {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

Repository

```
class BranchCurrencyRepository extends EntityRepository
{


    public function findAllActiveBuyingCurrencies() {

        return $this->createQueryBuilder('bc')
             ->where('bc.type = :type')
             ->setParameter('type', 1)
             ->orderBy('bc.currency', 'ASC');

        // $queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('bc')
        //         ->orWhere('bc.type =:type')
        //         ->setParameter('type', 2)
        //         ->orderBy('bc.currency', 'asc')
        //         ->setMaxResults(10);


    }


}
```

Comment: How many results do you expect and how many are shown instead? Is it browser related? And what if you only set multiple **or** expended to true?

Comment: @StephanVierkant if I set multiple and expanded to true, let us say the field is become checkbox. I got all the results, let us say 27/27. If I set to false and the field was drop down, I got 8/27 only.

Comment: It may be because your choice_label returns duplicates instead of returning distinct values.

Comment: @Tokeeen.com can you point out what is wrong?

Comment: return $currency->getId(); and check if you have all options.

Comment: @Tokeeen.com If I set return $currency->getId() in choice_level, and the expanded and multiple set to true. I still not get the complete records. If I set the multiple and expanded to false, I get all the records. Still not fix the bugs.

Comment: What if you set multiple to false, but expanded to true? And what if you set multiple to true, but expanded to false? You should figure out what **exactly** is going wrong and what's not.

Comment: I already figure it out. I tried to play with the configuration. set false and true to the parameters. the results are if the field is Radio or CheckBox the whole records are shown. If the field was Select or Drop down the records are incomplete.

Comment: @StephanVierkant I edit my question above, I just put the entity and repository class in case you want to see.

Comment: If I comment out the  'query_builder' => function (BranchCurrencyRepository $er) {
                    return $er->findAllActiveBuyingCurrencies();
                }, I see all the records. Maybe I have mistakes with repository class or query_builder?

Comment: If I change the value of  'choice_value' to id, I get all the results, I change to rate, I dont get the whole results.